# Ubuntu Server/Desktop 18.04 how update Vim from 8.0.1453 to 8.2

Tags: apt, upgrade, updates, vim

I am working with Ubuntu

- Server and Desktop

and both are based with the `18.04` version

I need work with `vim` - by default it is installed in Server - it has the `8.0.1453` version.

But in the Desktop is not installed, therefore for the Desktop I did the following:

- sudo apt update
- sudo apt upgrade
- sudo apt install vim

All ok, Vim is installed how is expected but again it is based for the `8.0.1453` version.

Even if in the Server I do

- sudo apt update
- sudo apt upgrade

Nothing to update but `Vim` remains with the `8.0.1453` version

I am confused because in [Vim - Download](https://www.vim.org/download.php) page has the following note:

```
Version

Vim 8.2 is the latest stable version. It is highly recommended, many bugs have been fixed since previous versions.
```

Therefore from `8.0.1453` to `8.2` there is a considerable difference between the releases.

I am *assuming* that I should do a reference for a special 'repository' (I had this experience through `MySQL`), which one? and from where I should take that 'official' reference?

Comment: Related: [Why don't the Ubuntu repositories have the latest versions of software?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/151283/why-dont-the-ubuntu-repositories-have-the-latest-versions-of-software). I suggest using `brew` for installing latest version of vim. You can also build from source or use a third-party PPA.

Comment: The `jonathonf/vim` PPA should have the new version.

Comment: @muru I saw the homepage of that project, it says `Unofficial package for Vim` ... therefore is safe work around there?

Comment: Depends on what you mean by safe. You can inspect the code  used for building those packages at https://git.launchpad.net/~jonathonf/+git/vim-packaging/tree/debian If you're willing to trust the word of a random stranger on the interwebs, I personally use it. If you don't trust random strangers and can't vet the build code, and won't build it yourself, then you should stick to the version in the Ubuntu repos unless you absolutely must have some new feature in 8.2.

Answer (score 1):

This is what the download page you've linked to suggests:

```
Unix
```

The best way to install Vim on Unix is to use the sources. This requires a compiler and its support files. Compiling Vim isn't difficult at all. You can simply type "make install" when you are happy with the default features. Edit the Makefile in the "src" directory to select specific features.

You need to download at the sources and the runtime files. And apply all the latest patches. For Vim 6 up to 7.2 you can optionally get the "lang" archive, which adds translated messages and menus. For 7.3 and later this is included with the runtime files.

Using git
    This is the simplest and most efficient way to obtain the latest version, including all patches. This requires the "git" command.
    The explanations are on the GitHub page.

```
Summary:

git clone https://github.com/vim/vim.git
cd vim/src
make
```

Using Mercurial
    This is another simple and most efficient way to obtain the latest version, including all patches. This requires the "hg" command.
    The explanations are on this page: Mercurial

```
Summary:

hg clone https://bitbucket.org/vim-mirror/vim
cd vim/src
make
```

You are probably ok with version 8.0.1453, but good luck anyway.

Comment: Thanks, according with many Linux tutorials, is wise avoid 'make' and work all through repositories ... if 8.0.1453 is ok, I will stay there